# Text file doesn't seem in simulator

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6, ios-simulator

I am new on Xcode and trying to learn Swift. My problem is with the view of the text-file in Simulator

In Main.storyboard the text-file is the centre of the display. However, when I run the IOS Simulator, the right end of the text file doesn't seem in Simulator.

Why does seem like that? What is the problem?

Comment: Sounds like you are using autolayout and not setting your constraints properly.

Comment: Maybe a screenshot would help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `autolayout` you will need to add constraints to make sure anything inside your window adjusts to the size of each device.

Here is an example screenshot where I am adding constraints to the sides of a Text View, make sure you click the red lines around the square and then click 'Add 4 Constraints' to set the constraints on each side.

[image: Auto Layout Example]

I suggest you read up on [Storyboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/SecondTutorial.html) and [Autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) before you continue.